# Compute dynamic edge weight in Gephi's dynamic network

Tags: gephi

Is it possible to have dynamic edge weight in dynamic graph in `Gephi`?

Let's say I have two nodes, A and B. The relation between these two nodes only presence for three times over the course of one month: in the first week, third week, and fourth week. I have successfully showed dynamic edges by creating a `GEXF` file with spells. But is it possible to assign edge weight by counting the number of spells covered by a given `timeframe`?

So if my `timeline` covers the first two weeks, the edge weight should be 1. If it covers the last two weeks, the weight should be 2. And if it covers the whole month, then the weight should be 3.

Anyone has any idea how to do it?